# How to open an app from web on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I create 'iframe' element, use the http scheme to open an app on Android Device, it works fine if the app is installed.

When the app is not installed, I use `setTimeout` function setting `window.location = marketurl`,
it will open market, and it works fine on *Android Browser*, but it doesn't work on *chrome 25+*.

I only see an error message in my browser.
What should I do?

Comment: don't you think it would be helpful to also include the error information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are some new changes to the functionality in Chrome for Android v. 25 and later. You may need to implement Intent. This is created to prevent unsafe app open from the browser.

Here is one example from Google Chrome for developers that will open the Zxing barcode scanner app.

```
<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>
```

Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

> It is no longer possible to launch an Android app by setting an
>   iframe's src attribute. For example, navigating an iframe to a URI
>   with a custom scheme such as paulsawesomeapp:// will not work even if
>   the user has the appropriate app installed. Instead, you should
>   implement a user gesture to launch the app via a custom scheme, or use
>   the “intent:” syntax described in this article.

Comment: Is it only works in Chrome? Should I separate code for Chrome browser and else?